# Capture printStackTrace() output in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm debugging an existing library that was not coded explicitly for Android.
It works, but contains lots of `ex.printStackTrace()` calls.
In Android, these are not written to the logcat by default.

My question is: without the possibility to modify the code, is it possible to somehow see the stack traces generated by `printStackTrace()` calls?

Comment: Hi, I think you make wrong. ex.printStackTrace() show in logcat. Select your device properly  to show logcat...<<<<<.

Comment: printStackTrace() will be logged to logcat.

Comment: Have you turned debugging on your device on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Android, these are not written to the logcat by default.

Sure they do.  They are written out at log level WARN, and the tag is usually `System.err`

Answer (score 0):

Print your stack trace and check the message in the Logcat (using DDMS) tool if you are working in Eclipse.

If not, use `adb logcat` in command line.

Either way, the results won't show any tags so you will have to guess which application they are coming from. If you want to know which application is sending them, you better use [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do by using getStackTrace.

Anyways, don't do this, as printing stack trace won't return which application cause the error. Use the Log class from java.util.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the code, you can't get anything that isn't written to the Log if it hasn't been coded originally. If you aren't seeing the PrintStackTrace, make sure that your device has the "debugg mode" enabled. Otherwise, no, without modifying the code, there isn't much you can do.

If you can modify the code, you could put the PrintStackTrace into a Log method:

```
Log.e(TAG, "custom message", ex);
```